# problems using threads in C++ on windows 10 (using g++ as compiler)

Tags: c++, multithreading, g++

I'm trying to create a thread and make it print something to the terminal. I was having some problems so I decided to take this very simple piece of code someone else made, when I compile it I get the errors listed below, but other people online seem to have no problem running this.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void hello_world()
{
    cout << "Hello from thread!\n";
}

int main()
{
    thread threadobj1(hello_world);
    threadobj1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler (mingw32-gcc-g++-bin 8.2.0.3 on windows 10) gives the following errors:

```
.\multiT.cpp: In function 'int main()':
.\multiT.cpp:13:5: error: 'thread' was not declared in this scope
     thread threadobj1(hello_world);
     ^~~~~~
.\multiT.cpp:13:5: note: 'std::thread' is defined in header '<thread>'; did you forget to '#include <thread>'?.\multiT.cpp:3:1:
+#include <thread>

.\multiT.cpp:13:5:
     thread threadobj1(hello_world);
     ^~~~~~
.\multiT.cpp:14:5: error: 'threadobj1' was not declared in this scope
     threadobj1.join();
     ^~~~~~~~~~
.\multiT.cpp:14:5: note: suggested alternative: 'thread_local'
     threadobj1.join();
     ^~~~~~~~~~
     thread_local
```

I was hoping someone might be able to help me figure out why this isn't working for me, the error says I should include , but I've clearly already done that so I'm a bit lost now. I've already tried to install the "mingw32-pthreads-w32-dev" packages as those weren't installed but that hasn't made any difference. I've also added the following arguments to the compiler:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -pthread .\multiT.cpp
```

Comment: Did you download the compiler from http://mingw.org/ ? ISTR it does not implement a working <thread>.

Comment: GCC needs to be built with threads enabled. But you can use the windows thread functions instead.

Comment: MinGW is almost dead. [mingw-64](https://mingw-w64.org/) however should support C++11 threads. – *I 've always felt like visual studio is a bit bloated?* – Maybe, but you'll get one of the finest IDEs with great debugger and ice cream.

Comment: @Swordfish Wow I had no idea mingw-64 existed, I guess that that's what I deserve for following tutorials from 2015. :/ I'll try installing that now. To be far the last time I tried doing stuff with visual studio I was 15 and had a way slower computer so I probably shouldn't judge it too hard based on those experiences.

Comment: @Swordfish Well, I just finished installing mingw-64, compiling gave an error again but that was easily fixed with the ```-std=gnu++11``` option to enable 'experimental' features. And it now works like a charm! Thank you Swordfish!

Comment: You're welcome! Now you can write an answer to your question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For anyone else dealing with this problem:** The simplest solution is to download [mingw-64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) and use their compiler instead.

Then use the `-std=gnu++11` or `-std=c++11` arguments to enable support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard and by extension support for threads (do note: This support is currently experimental, though that has not given me any problems so far).

Comment: How/where do you add these arguments? can you please clarify?

Comment: @hago In the command line/makefile that you use to invoke the compiler, just like any other arguments like `-O3` or something: `g++ -std=c++11 myfile.cpp`.

Comment: I got the same issue on there as well.